# Varnish: Make cache dependent on X-Forwarded-Proto https

Tags: http, caching, header, varnish

following situation:
On the server is a apache and Varnish for caching. SSL is handled by an amazon load balancer.
If the page is requested using https, the http header "X-Forwarded-Proto" is set to "https".
The pages are sometimes different (e.g. links/images have to be fetched using https when using a secure connection)

How can I tell varnish that pages are different if the X-Forwarded-Proto header differs?
As it is now, whatever is accessed first is cached and served for http and https!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if ( req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto !~ "(?i)https") {
        set req.http.x-Redir-Url = "http://" + ...req url;
    }else{
        set req.http.x-Redir-Url = "https://" + ...req url;
    }
}
```

Sorry, I have updated the code now. This is what I meant.

Comment: thanks but I don't want to redirect all users to https! I just want varnish to deliver different pages for http and https, not the same!

Comment: The above one is the example that appears in the Varnish Page. But it shows you where and how to handle the requests based on the 'X-Forwarded-Proto'
It would need to use the proper values within the if-else

Comment: ok, but I don't know how/if I can tell varnish to cache the page, but with anoter key. I just see how to cache it or don't!

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need, but for the sake of clarity I have updated the code now. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 5):

What you want, I presume, is to have different cached versions of the same URI, that's pretty easy using a custom `vcl_hash`:

```
sub vcl_hash {
  # ...
  if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto &&
      req.url !~ "(?i)\.(png|gif|jpeg|jpg|ico|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|zip|rar|otf|ttf|eot|woff|svg|pdf)$") {
     hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
  }
  # ...
}
```

In this example static files are only cached once and the rest (html, js, css..) are cached in 2 different versions (assuming X-Forwarded-Proto only takes two values).

You can see the example in a broader context on https://github.com/NITEMAN/varnish-bites/blob/master/varnish3/drupal-base.vcl

Answer (score 4):

The question and the answers are pretty old.

By now best practice is to utilize the `Vary` header (ironically, what the guy suggested who got his answer deleted in 2015).

You should avoid the `hash_data()` as much as possible.

Your backend should instead send `Vary: X-Forwarded-Proto,Accept-Encoding`. The Varnish server sees the header and does create seperate cache entries according to the protocol in the header set by the terminating instance.

Comment: Would be great if you could add a source why hash_data should be avoided!

Comment: I second that.. why should `hash_data()` be avoided as much as possible?  @NITEMAN's answer seems legit to me...

Comment: @YesBarry @Josef It's not "bad" to use `hash_data()`, but, the decisions, which URLs from the backend do have variations, is a decision made by the backend/application, not by Varnish. Wether a website has variations for mobile/desktop devices, is in power of the website-project, not in power of Varnish. The `Vary` headers purpose is to signal variations to the downstream instance. Seperation of concerns!

Comment: @Josef One more thing: There is no way you can directly edit the configuration of a downstream cache instance in a foreign network run by a foreign company. So again, you use `Vary` header to tell the downstream cache to build variations of a specific host+url combination.

Comment: @DanFromGermany in this case, for anyone outside the documents have a different URL. One starts with http:// the other with https://
The X-Forwarded-Proto header is also striped in Varnish.
In general, what you say makes sense.

Comment: @Josef For me it's not just semantically better to not do this in varnish, but also because Vary header are universal. They work without configuration and they work with all proxies, not only with Varnish. Imagine you stop using Varnish and move to something else, and all this caching works without having to learn and build a new configuration. Also when you want to disable providing a http and https version, you would simply stop sending the Vary header - no configuration in varnish needs to be done.

Comment: @DanFromGermany thanks for the response!  I actually did go with your answer and it solved my problem. But I ended up commenting after the fact just out of curiosity.  Might I suggest you add some of that to your actual answer?  Thanks!